# Unity3D C# - Getting the type of a script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, im created a placement system for placing objects on a grid, i have the grid and the placement all works, my issue is im trying to create a "ghost" object which exists while im placing but doesn't actually do anything, my problem is im trying to figure out a way to destroy/deactivate any and ALL "SCRIPTS" attached to any child of the ghost object, so none of them work. But i can't figure out what System.Type a script is. Anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

Call to:

```
gameobject.GetComponents(typeof(Component));
```

That will return all the components. Caution with the default Unity components: Transform, Mesh... you can determine the type with *is* or *IsInstanceOfType* or *component.GetType()* for cast the Component objects if necesary.

Answer (score 0):

Using `gameobject.GetComponent(typeof(Component));` will return all the components attached to that game objects but not all the components of children. However, there is a way you can get all the components of of all the children user `gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren(typeof(Component));`, but I don't recommend using `Component` instead you should use `MonoBehaviour` using this type you'll only get those components which are directly derived from `MonoBehaviour` which include your scripts as well. After that, you can check for **.(dot)**, as almost all of the Unity's built-in components are in the namespace `UnityEngine`. And `Object.GetType()` will return the type in the following format `namespace.ObjectType`.

Here if you check for the index of **.(dot)** if the given type includes the **.(dot)** it will return its position. If the **.(dot)** don't exist in the string it will return `-1`. Check for the `-1` we can make sure that the components are not in any namespace and is safe to destroy. I hope that you got what I'm trying to say, if not it's ok just see the code snippet below you'll get the idea.

```
Component[] c = ghost.GetComponentsInChildren(typeof(MonoBehaviour));
     foreach(Component cmp in c)
     {
         if(cmp.GetType().ToString().IndexOf('.') <= -1)
         {
             Destroy(cmp);
         }
     }
```